# How to solve NoClassDefError Exception by adding Library to Java Runtime Jar in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Im trying to import jar.
I brought it in the library and module dependencies of IntelliJ's project settings.

I cant seem to bring this library to the run-time jar. It gives me no library at run-time and only works at compile. I'm trying to use Commons-IO that uses `FileUtils` for file/directory manipulation.

[image: IDEA is being difficult]

Comment: Looks like you're running it from the command line?  Either run it inside IntelliJ (using the Run command, or from the terminal window for example), or make sure your classpath is set correctly when you call the command line.

Comment: I was running it through a .bat that launches the command line. It works great within the compile in the IDE, but didn't bring the library when it was deploying the .jar. IT now works. I just had to set the JDK to be 1.7 and have it deploy so JRE 7 could run it.